# Increase width and height of Bitmap without stretching or recreating

Tags: vb.net, image, graphics, resize

For the last few weeks I've been working on a program that creates a bitmap that has a grid on it, which every time I want to change the image, I recreate it with

```
    gridBMP = New Bitmap(gridColumns * boxWidth, gridRows * boxHeight)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(gridBMP)
    Dim p As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0)) ' Create a new pen, black
    Dim b As New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0)) ' Create a new solid brush, black

    Dim wallPen As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 192, 192, 192)) ' Create a new pen, Grey

    Dim maxWidth As Integer = pb_grid.Width ' Get Max width
    Dim maxHeight As Integer = pb_grid.Height ' Get Max height

    g.Clear(Color.White) ' Make white background

    For i = 0 To gridColumns ' Draw Column lines
        Dim val As Integer = i * boxWidth
        g.DrawLine(wallPen, New Point(val, 0), New Point(val, maxHeight))
    Next

    For i = 0 To gridRows ' Draw Row lines
        Dim val As Integer = i * boxHeight
        g.DrawLine(wallPen, New Point(0, val), New Point(maxWidth, val))
    Next

    ' Draw borders at bottom and right
    g.DrawLine(wallPen, New Point(0, maxHeight), New Point(maxWidth, maxHeight))
    g.DrawLine(wallPen, New Point(maxWidth, 0), New Point(maxWidth, maxHeight))

    drawAll(g, p, b) ' Draw all objects

    pb_grid.Image = gridBMP

    ' Dispose of brush and pen
    p.Dispose()
    b.Dispose()
```

As you see at the end I set the picturebox image as the bitmap with `pb_grid.Image = gridBMP`

But is there an easier way to do this? Because currently recreating the image everytime seems to be very intensive and takes a second or two to update the image, which I don't want, I would like it to be near to instant as possible with the form, but I cannot figure out how to 'Increase' the width of the grid, without recreating the whole image, which takes time.

I've tried a background worker, but it's really no difference because the image takes so long anyways.

Any thoughts and suggestions are welcome!

Thanks

Comment: If this is a native windows application and you want to draw a grid, why not draw directly onto the form with some lines? Why generate the image at all?

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean by draw directly to the form, the main reason I created an image was because in the `drawAll()` function it iterates through multiple multidimensional arrays that hold pictures and strings to be displayed within the grid, which is high intensive to do on the paint event from my experience, so I decided creating an image that it can access and not have to remake on everyone paint event was more ideal

Comment: Changing your proceeding is virtually impossible (you are accounting for multiple small images and the only way to not affect their appearance while resizing the container resizing is changing the size of each of them (and the drawn borders)). It might be possible to optimise your algorithm; can you please post the code in "drawAll()" to get a complete picture of what is going on?